# Conflito $ entre scripts

Tags: jquery

Eu estou tentando usar esses dois scripts:

http://suprb.com/apps/gridalicious/js/jquery.grid-a-licious.js
http://suprb.com/apps/gridalicious/js/jquery.fittext.js

Porém eu uso jQuery e Prorotype na mesma página, e para evitar conflito entre eles eu coloquei esse código `$JQUERY = jQuery.noConflict();`

Funciona ok, mas não consigo adaptar esses dois scripts para que eles usem o `$JQUERY` ao invés do `$`.

Como eu posso modifica-los?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esses script estão preparados para correr em modo de não conflito. Precisas somente de correr `jQuery.noConflict();`.

Para ter a certeza que tudo corre bem podes juntar nesta ordem:

```js
document.body.innerHTML = [
  'Prototype.Version: ' + Prototype.Version,
  '<br/>',
  'jQuery.version: ' + jQuery.fn.jquery
].join('');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script src="http://suprb.com/apps/gridalicious/js/jquery.grid-a-licious.js"></script>
<script src="http://suprb.com/apps/gridalicious/js/jquery.fittext.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.3.0/prototype.js"></script>
```